# Broken Ads Api after 3rd October 2013

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

Looks like after October 2013 breaking changes ADS api is not working fine . Earlier call to url

https://graph.facebook.com/act_{act id}/adcampaigns?access_token={access token}

will return

Values like

{"id":"{value}","frequency_cap":0,"account_id":{value},"name":"{value}"}

But now the output returns like

{"id":"{value}"}

Can some one please confirm ?

Comment: i need to start facebook ads api integration into my website. please give some details. facebook give more and more documents so i totally confused. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the changes made in the October 2013 breaking changes and is [documented on the 'Completed Changes' part of the roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)

> **Adcampaign endpoint**
>
> Removing campaign_id and include_budget_remaining flag. You must now
> specify query params when retrieving information about adgroups. The
> only field returned by default will be id. See docs for more detail.

Comment: @Igy i need to start facebook ads api integration into my website. please give some details. facebook give more and more documents so i totally confused. please help me